# How to activate customer accounts in bulk?

Tags: magento-1.9

After applying the patches:

- SUPEE-10415
- SUPEE-10570
- SUPEE-10752
- PATCH-PHP72

In a **Magento v.1.9.3.6** all clients get the message *'This account is not activated.'* when trying to login.

**How can I restore all customer accounts massively?** ('admin' or database)

Can it be a problem with any of the patches?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify with below options :

have you check with customer is active or not ?

```
System > Settings > Customer Options > Customer Activation
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Thank you @anas-mansuri for your answer. Unfortunately this 'Customer Activation' section isn't in my list. Maybe this section come from a module?

Comment: in admin customer grid check with its active ?

Comment: The grid don't show check for _is active_, but inside the customer information, has '1' as value and is confirmed is 'confirmed'.